# Releasing Object is it necessary?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, xcode4

I am stuck in the middle of memory management stuff. Please help me  out in solving my question.

```
NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
Object *obj = [[Object alloc]init];  
[array addObject: obj];  
[obj release];
```

Is it necessary to release `obj` in above code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer to your question is: yes, if you don't use [ARC](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#releasenotes/ObjectiveC/RN-TransitioningToARC/Introduction/Introduction.html). If you are writing a new app, you should seriously consider using ARC.

*Container objects in Objective-C always balance their retain/release count.* In other words, you should always manage memory as if you did not add the object and make sure your own code balances its retain count. Note that this is a convention and is not enforced, but you could always trust the built-in classes to follow this convention. Also, you can perform a static analysis (Cmd+Shift+B in XCode) to detect these problems. It would have pinpointed this in your code above.

The correct code in the case above would be:

```
NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
Object *obj = [[[Object alloc]init]autorelease];
[array addObject: obj];
```

or

```
NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
Object *obj = [[Object alloc]init];
[array addObject: obj];
[obj release];
```

since `NSMutableArray` (and its cousins) will retain the object as long as it is in the collection.

Comment: but i released array here... i thing it will send release methode to object.. please correct me if i am wrong

Comment: Releasing the array has nothing to do with it. The array always balances release/retain. Of course, forgetting to release the array would introduce a leak regardless of if the object was released.